# python osmnx - extract only big freeways of a country

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I know it is possible to extract the road network of a city via the OSMNX python package. See details at https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/ .

```
paris_network = ox.gdf_from_place("Paris")
```

But, let's say I do not want that level of high details, but rather only big freeways of a whole country. I'm looking for something like :

```
france_big_expressway_network = ox.gdf_from_place("France", road_type = "freeway")
```

I guess it might comes from the "infrastructure" argument but as a newbie I really do not get how to use it precisely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do this with OSMnx:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True
cf = '["highway"~"motorway"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place('France', network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897000/7321942) if you'd like to filter by multiple highway tag values (e.g., retain all motorways AND primary roads).

See the [OSMnx docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io) for more usage details.

Comment: I use this for "Brazil", it eats all the 150GB RAM of our server and then the python kernel died!