# How to import multiple infrastructure type in osmnx?

Tags: osmnx

Is there any way to specify multiple subcategories for an infrastructure type while importing roads using osmnx. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52231122/9801811) I understand that we can select only freeways by specifying `infrastructure='way["highway"~"motorway"]'`. How can we expand this to include multiple categories such as `highways = motorway or primary or secondary` or `highway is not footway`

I tried the following without success:

```
infrastructure='way["highway"~"motorway"],way["highway"~"primary"]'
infrastructure='way["highway"~"motorway", "primary"]'
infrastructure='way["highway"~"motorway" OR "primary"]'
```

It would be nice to have better filtering such as  `highway=primary or highway=primary_link`  ([examples here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30692/export-only-roads) , [keys here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pipe `|` as an overpass `or` operator like:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.settings.log_console = True
place = 'Berkeley, California, USA'

cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
print(len(G)) #36

cf = '["highway"~"primary"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
print(len(G)) #11

cf = '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|primary"]'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', custom_filter=cf)
print(len(G)) #47
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942