# OSMnx: combine several multidirectional graphs

Tags: python, osmnx

I used OSMnx to retrieve the road networks in France. For execution time constraints, I retrieved the data department by department: While trying to retrieve the road network of all of France at once, my script ran for 4 days without results. Therefore, I retrieve the data department by department. I stored the data on disk, and now I need to combine the graphs of all the departments to obtain the complete road network of France.

Is there any function with OSMnx to combine several graphs into one?

Below is my code to retrieve data by department

```
departments = ["Ain","Aisne", "Alpes de Haute-Provence",..., "Seine-Saint-Denis", "Val-de-Marne", "Val-d'Oise"]

    for department in departments:
        DepartemntName = department + ",France"
        G = ox.graph_from_place(DepartmentName, network_type="drive")
        filePathToSave = "AllDepartmentsData/" + department +".graphml"
        ox.save_graphml(G,filePathToSave)
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883614/7321942 regarding networkx.compose()

Answer (score 1):

Use `Networkxx` library and its function `compose_all()` to combine a list of `MultiDiGraph` objects (your graphs).

```
import networkx as nx

graphs = [graph0, graph1, ..., graphN] # list of MultiDiGraph

full_graph = nx.compose_all(graphs)
```