# How to deal with large maps in osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

What is the best way to calculate the shortest street distance between two locations which cover a large distance using OSmnx. For example, if I was trying to find a route across the US?

Doing this seems burdensome, and perhaps impossible given my compute resources.

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('USA', network_type='drive')

orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (lat, lon))
dest_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (lat, lon))

nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig_node, dest_node, weight='length')
```

Any efficient methods to do this?

I did see this post..

[python osmnx - extract only big freeways of a country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231122/python-osmnx-extract-only-big-freeways-of-a-country/52412274#52412274)

but even just the freeways in the US will create a huge network

Answer (score 2):

Given the enormity of your study site and the likely limitations of your computer, your best bet may be to first [download](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) an OSM extract then load it with OSMnx's [graph_from_xml](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_xml) function.

Comment: I am querying OSMnx also for a very large study site (gpx route between Amsterdam and Rome - polygon of 1.5km radius around the route) for all the tourism places (I want all the area I could sleep: camp_sites, hotels etc.). Unfortunately, the API is only returning empty file to the cache... Is this caused by a too large study area? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75144426/retrieve-campsites-within-a-specific-radius-around-a-gpx-route-from-osm