# Is it possible to create a map of the highway network for a country using OSMnx?

Tags: python, osmnx

I know that if I try to create a map of a country, I'm going to get a file that's way too big. What I would like is to be able to create a lighter map that would only take into account the motorway network with the cities as nodes. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52231122/7321942

Comment: Thanks for showing me this post, I had missed it. My question is clearly a duplicate